# Oracle SQL XML Parsing Error because of apostrophe in XML output

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, parsing, format

I'm currently producing XML files from Oracle SQL but have come up against a problem when opening up the XML file in a web browser, I get the below message. This indicates the offending character

```
 XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
 Location: file://///data2/data/Download/d7prdv1/prsrepreports/test_error_2.xml
 Line Number 80, Column 29:          <musicTitle>NATURES SHADOW LOUNGE</musicTitle>
```

which is due to the **musicTitle** field having an apostrophe (i.e. the offending apostrophe is shown in the following "NATURE'S SHADOW LOUNGE" ).

After doing a dump of the string above it was found that the apostrophe was in fact chr(146) which is a different apostrophe.

How do I overcome the apostrophe problem in my XML output, as this could happen in other fields? I've added an extract of the SQL below just for info purposes, would I need to replace the apostrophe with a space? The data is loaded into the database from different companies from around the world, so they could be using differing characters.

```
  XMLELEMENT ("musicWork", -- start level 6 tag for music title
            XMLFOREST (cc.title AS "musicTitle"), -- start level 7 tag for music title       
                  XMLFOREST (
                          XMLFOREST ( cc.source_album_title AS "albumTitle",
                                      cc.product_album_promo_title AS "promoTitle",
                                      cc.label AS "label",
                                      cc.catalogue_no AS "catalogNumber",
                                      cc.isrc AS "isrc") AS "recordingInfo" 
                                    )  -- end level 7 tag for music title
```

I was thinking of creating the below function, replacing each invalid character with a NULL. Is this the way to go and how would I put chr(146) in the below FUNCTION rather than the character, to ensure I'm getting the offending character?

```
    FUNCTION CONVERT_VALUE (INPUT_STRING IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
        l_string_converted   VARCHAR2(300);
        BEGIN

        l_string_converted := REGEXP_REPLACE (INPUT_STRING, '*|£|~|^|_', '', 1, 0, 'i');

        RETURN l_string_converted;

    END CONVERT_VALUE;
```

So the CONVERT_VALUE function would then be called within my SQL XML script.

```
   XMLELEMENT ("musicWork", -- start level 6 tag for music title
            XMLFOREST (CONVERT_VALUE(cc.title) AS "musicTitle"), -- start level 7 tag for music title       
                  XMLFOREST (
                          XMLFOREST ( CONVERT_VALUE(cc.source_album_title) AS "albumTitle",
                                      CONVERT_VALUE(cc.product_album_promo_title) AS "promoTitle",
                                      cc.label AS "label",
                                      cc.catalogue_no AS "catalogNumber",
                                      cc.isrc AS "isrc") AS "recordingInfo" 
                                    )  -- end level 7 tag for music
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Shaun, could you provide the Unicode code point of this character? It doesn't look like the regular apostrophe, which is actually allowed in element content. It may be a character that is not allowed in XML at all, or it may be an encoding issue.

Comment: An actual apostrophe should be encoded as `&apos;`. What do you see if you run the query directly in SQL\*Plus? What does `select dump(title) from...` show for that row in the original table? (You can add that as an edit to the question so it can be formatted)

Comment: ... and if you are not familiar with `dump()` - if you try the query Alex suggested, with the condition `WHERE title LIKE '%SHADOW LOUNGE'` so you only get the desired row - if I dump `NATURE'S SHADOW LOUNGE` I get `Typ=96 Len=22: 78,65,84,85,82,69,39,83,32,83,72,65,68,79,87,32,76,79,85,78,71,69` The seventh code is 39, that is the ASCII code for the "normal" single quote. Is that what you get, too?

Comment: Thanks! Assuming notepad++ opens with the right encoding, it looks like &#x2013;, so it's in the allowed range [#x20-#xD7FF]. However, this is an en dash, not an apostrophe so it may still be a different encoding. Does Notepad++ tell you the encoding it used to open it, and does the XML file produced by Oracle begin with a byte order mark (#xFEFF) and/or declare its encoding on the first line? Also something coming to my mind: does it help to change the encoding used by the browser in which this file is opened to the same as notepad++? With no BOM/encoding declared, it has to be read as UTF-8.

Comment: I select the record from the database and the field record just looks like a normal apostrophe which seems strange

Comment: I'll do what Alex has suggest with the dump

Comment: Dumping the string will tell you if it really is a plain apostrophe or something that just looks similar. The character in the error message seems to be `efbfbf` but it might be being corrupted somewhere else.. Seeing what the SQL produces would be interesting too. And what is your DB character set?

Comment: Thanks Shaun. It's strange indeed. Assuming the dump confirms that it's what it is, the normal apostrophe is ASCII and should not cause more problems than letters or digits, it does not need to be escaped either in element content. I'd still do trial and error to switch encodings in the browser, beginning with UTF-8, to see if there is one that fixes the error and could indicate the one Oracle used to write.

Comment: I did a dump an got this 146 like you say should be 39 now that's strange Typ=1 Len=22: 78,65,84,85,82,69,146,83,32,83,72,65,68,79,87,32,76,79,85,78,71,69 not sure how to overcome this

Comment: @ShaunKinnair - it's not that strange; 146 is the right single-quotation mark. It may look exactly the same in your typeface. This seems to happen a lot when test is copied in from an external editor what uses 'smart' quotes, e.g. Word. Why your XML ends up with codepoint `ffff` instead of that character is still odd though.

Comment: I expect this is an encoding problem; what is your database character set, what is your client's NLS_LANG, and what is the encoding of the file that's produced? Once of them appears to not like ASCII 146 being treated as Unicode 146 (0092) I think, but had to tell exactly where it's getting confused. (Maybe you can replace curly quotes with straight ones in your data?)

Comment: Hi Alex, the data is loaded into the database from different incoming files from different companies, so I suspect that this is how it came to be in the database. I guess for my program I need to replace every invalid character either with a space or the correct character, maybe using REGEXP_REPLACE, I'll update the post to include this I think. Once again Alex thanks for your feedback it's always a big help

Comment: They are only invalid because your character set (at some point int he process) doesn't recognise them. Trying to find and replace anything that might be invalid sounds painful. Fixing your client/file encoding would be easier.

Comment: If you just wanted to do the normal XML escapes you could use `DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT` but it won't help with right-apostrophe. Thanks to @Alex for the correction to my original post.