# XML Oracle SQL character sets ORA-31011: XML parsing failed

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, parsing

I have a XML SQL statement that I'm using (see below Oracle11g SQL) to overcome a passing error (below), the SQL statement works but it does strip out characters that are not specified in the `REGEXP_REPLACE` statement for example the following `É Ë È` that need to be included in my XML output file, I could include these and more but is there a short cut to include these characters as well in the `REGEXP_REPLACE` without naming a long list of characters. I have tried SQL `select DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(T.title)` as I've been told this strips out all invalid characters but this failed with the same parsing error as below.

The reason why I'm using `REGEXP_REPLACE`, as it was failing because of certain characters (for example `char(160)` none-breaking space) that were in the title database field.

Is there a simpler solution or do I have to included a long list of characters in the `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

Thanks in advance.

```
DECLARE 
*
ERROR at line:
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

The trouble is because I'm dealing with different character

```
SELECT XMLAGG ( XMLELEMENT ("referenceAvGroup",                                                               
                   XMLFOREST (cre_surr_id AS "societySeriesNumber",
                              'SERIES' AS "avGroupType"),
                          XMLELEMENT ("prodTitle",                                                                   
                                 XMLFOREST (title AS "title",
                                            tt_code_description AS "titleType")
                                      )                                                                         
                            )
               )                                                                      
FROM (  SELECT trim(REGEXP_REPLACE(T.title, '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,!@():.#’"*&+}/\©{ÂÀÃÏÎÔÜ€Ç¿%´_$()'',-`]', '', 1, 0, 'i')) AS title,
                'ORIGINAL'  AS tt_code_description,
                T.tt_code AS tt_codes,
                T.cre_surr_id
        FROM    titles T
        WHERE   T.tt_code = Com0300.title_type_registered) 
WHERE cre_surr_id = prod.prod_series_cre_surr_id
```

Comment: It might be easier to maintain a list of characters you want to replace...

Comment: Can you update your question to include sample data that replicates the issue you are seeing, please?

Comment: What is set in this parameter? SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS where parametrer= 
'NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP'

Comment: Looks like you have a lot of trouble with your XML; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40493076/ora-31011-xml-parsing-failed-invalid-characters-oracle-sql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877171/oracle-sql-xml-parsing-error-because-of-apostrophe-in-xml-output Why the hell do you like to remove special characters? It is not the source of your problem.

Comment: Try `UTL_I18N.ESCAPE_REFERENCE(title, 'us7ascii')`

Comment: According to your previous question you import file `file://///data2/data/Download/d7prdv1/prsrepreports/test_error_2.xml`. Apparently this file is declared as `UTF-8` but it is not in reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an update in the end I went with the below. There seem to be a lot of control characters that had been loaded from files into the database, which were causing my SQL XML not to parse. After using the below and removing these characters my SQL XML ran fine. Thanks for all your advice on this subject.

regexp_replace(replace(prod.CAMPAIGN_NAME,chr(160),''),'[[:cntrl:]]')